# Links not working after disabling IScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, dom-events, iscroll

When I initialize **[IScroll](http://iscrolljs.com/)** with `click` property:

```
var myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { click: true });
```

And then try to disable IScroll:

```
myScroll.disable();
```

I have an issue where all the **links don't work anymore**.

Here is a simple jsfiddle (based on IScroll demo) showing what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/gregmatys/Dxw6r/2/

Answer (score 0):

Catch the URL and trigger links by jquery:

```
var url = $(this).attr('href');
$('#scroller a').on(click, function() {
    window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dxw6r/3/